# How to backup/restore specific apps for new phone?

Tags: backup

I'm switching from OnePlus 6 to Nothing Phone and just want to backup some (from some apps not all apps) app data without root access. What are my options?

I've read several articles but their mentioning outdated methods, root methods or just .apk backup methods without app data.

Comment: AFAIK whne migrating to a new phone there is no way for a selective backup(restore. `adb backup` doesn't work anymore on recent phone for non-outdated apps. This leaves you to backup/restore via cloud or direct USB connection between old & new phone. IMHO the best option is the USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

This has never been very successful for me.  Available methods are

- For me its `Samsung Smartswitch`,
- There is `OnePlus Switch`
- Otherwise `Android Backup and Restore`
- Helium Backup
- Titanium Backup

You install them on both devices, some work with wifi, some with cable, others either way. The following is based on Samsung Smartswitch but I believe its the same with the OnePlus and Android toosl.  I have not tried Helium or Titanium Backups.

- It copies all apps (that are free) and their data.
- It does not copy paid apps or their data or both.  *I can understand this, otherwise it could be used to make copies of them with payment record intact*
- You have to re-register the paid-up apps again.  Some recognise that they were paid for before, others do not.
- You have to re-register apps such as banking apps and authentication apps.